# How to change Postgresql concat function timestamp to string used format for conversion?

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, psql

I have the following code :

```
start transaction;

show datestyle;

set datestyle to DMY;
show datestyle;

select 
   concat(timestamp_field, '')
from
   my_table
   ;
   
commit;
```

It outputs this :

```
 DateStyle
-----------
 ISO, DMY
(1 ligne)


 DateStyle (after set datestyle to DMY;)
-----------
 ISO, DMY
(1 ligne)


select 
   concat(timestamp_field, '')
from
   my_table
   ;
       concat
---------------------
 2004-09-01 00:00:00
(1 lignes)
```

My datestyle change doesn't seem to be accepted. Moreover, concat keeps using ISO to format my `timestamp_field`. I would expect something like this :

```
       concat
---------------------
 01/09/2004 00:00:00
(1 lignes)
```

> *NOTA:* I don't want to use `to_char` function here. I want to understand how concat automagically convert a timestamp field.

Comment: Just a PSA: never rely on a function like that to automatically convert a timestamp to text, if you care at all about the format. You should be explicit about the conversion, using something like `to_char`. Knowing the answer to your question for the sake of curiosity is fine, but you definitely shouldn't be using `concat` to convert a timestamp to text.

Comment: Perhaps you want `SQL,DMY`

Comment: (`ISO` impies `YMD`)

Comment: Read this [DateStyle](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT) section of the docs. `DateStyle` is a two part configuration and not all the first parts support `DMY` in the second part.